# Latency on a domain workstation when accessing a network share

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, connection

This is the first time I've ever posted a question on any blog, but I'm at my wits end. I have a domain with about 50 users. I have one system that when trying to access a file share on a server in the domain, it takes an extraordinary amount of time to load, but eventually will, if you just let it do it's thing. It doesn't matter what profile I log in with (user or admin) the problem is the same.

I took the system off the users desk and connected it at my desk. Everything works fine. Files load quickly. So I thought, it was something on that network port. To test, I brought a different system to that users desk and connected it. Oddly, the connection to the shares was fast and loaded quickly on both a user and admin profile. I replaced the users system and the problem returned.

I can access the internet no problem, no latency. I can ping the server at less than 1ms. I flushed the DNS. I cleared the ARP. I updated everything. I tried in Safe Mode. I disabled Add-ons. I added the server to the host file. I don't know what else it could be.

Why does it work at a different network jack and why does a different system work on that jack?

No one else has issues.

Windows 7 and Server 2012.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

7/20 - More Information.... Just to clarify a few things. My desk network and the network this system is on are different subnets that are NATed through the router. When i brought this system to my desk it was on the 192.168.10.x network and worked fine. The network that this system is typically on is 192.168.0.x. When I bring another system over to this desk and connect to the same jack, I connect to the 192.168.0.x network and can access the shares on the server no problem. The server is on the 192.168.10.x network. I can upload from the workstation to the server no problem. It's only down from the server I'm having issues.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the NIC. Is it possible for you to add a new card, or change the old one?

Comment: Thanks Alex. If it was a NIC issue, I would think I would have the same issue when connected to a different jack. Also, I have no issues connecting to the internet and pinging the server with no drops.

Comment: How many TCP retransmissions are shown in `netstat -s`?

Comment: TCP Statistics for IPv4

  Active Opens                        = 3588
  Passive Opens                       = 704
  Failed Connection Attempts          = 102
  Reset Connections                   = 1583
  Current Connections                 = 6
  Segments Received                   = 243481
  Segments Sent                       = 240415
  Segments Retransmitted              = 845

Answer (score 0):

To test if it is hardware related, you can try a different network cable, other different network jack. Also you can connect your desk to this user's network jack.

Since you have replaced the system which solved the problem, it clears the network cache(port, network type etc).

Comment: I'm very confident it is not the NIC. Internet connectivity is fine, I can upload to the server fine. I'm thinking it is one of three things. There is something going on with this machine and it's ability to download from the server or something in server that is preventing a clean download to this machine or something in the network itself. I am struggling with how to isolate where the problem is. It's not related to profiles, because it happens across all profiles. I also disabled Sophos AV with no change.